# Allow non-root users ioctl access to /dev/mytest file in linux module

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module, device-driver

My project contains two things: kernel module & app, that are communicating via `ioctl` using `/dev/mytest` file.

Currently, app is required to be run as root to access `/dev/mytest` file. Is it possible to allow non-users to iteract with this file without sudo?

As i understood, file_operations structure property `.owner = THIS_MODULE` has nothing about `/dev/mytest` file and is associated only with driver file.

I create `/dev/mytest` using `class_create` & `device_create` functions in kernel module. So, perhaps i should specify some special `device_create` parameters? Or how i can achieve it?

Comment: Write a udev rule for your device. Don't hardcode the permissions in the driver.

Comment: @n.m. it's education-purposes driver, i want to simplify it's usage as possible.

Comment: @n.m. You suggestion about udev was very informative. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a modern kernel, you can do something like

```
  myclass = class_create(THIS_MODULE, "my_class_name");
  /* error handling if class_create fails */
  myclass->devnode = mydevnode;
```

where your `devnode` function is something like

```
  static char *mydevnode(struct device *dev, umode_t *mode)
  {
      if (mode)
          *mode = 0666; /* or whatever permissions you want */
      return NULL; /* could override /dev name here too */
  }
```

then if you use `device_create` to create your driver special file, the kernel will call `mydevnode` to create the file, and you can override the file permissions there.